# Add dynamic markers on angular using API v3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add multiple markers dynamically in my map's controller, but I can't get the id to iterate and show all my markers, how can I set it to get all of the markers and show them correctly, The error tha I'm getting is:

Marker model has no id to assign a child to. This is required for performance. Please assign id, or redirect id to a different key

```
ShowList.enderecoViagem(viagens_id).then(function (listview) {
            $scope.enderecos = listview;


            uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {


                $scope.googlemap = {};
                $scope.map = {
                    center: {
                        latitude: $scope.enderecos[0].latitude,
                        longitude: $scope.enderecos[0].longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 14,
                    pan: 1,
                    options: $scope.mapOptions,
                    control: {},
                    events: {
                        tilesloaded: function (maps, eventName, args) {},
                        dragend: function (maps, eventName, args) {},
                        zoom_changed: function (maps, eventName, args) {}
                    }
                };
            });

            $scope.windowOptions = {
                show: false
            };



            $scope.title = "Window Title!";

            uiGmapIsReady.promise() // if no value is put in promise() it defaults to promise(1)
                .then(function (instances) {
                    console.log(instances[0].map); // get the current map
                })
                .then(function () {
                    $scope.addMarkerClickFunction($scope.markers);
                });

           for(var i = 0; i < $scope.enderecos.length; i++) {


               $scope.markers = [];

               $scope.markers.push({
                   id:[i],
                   latitude: $scope.enderecos[i].latitude,
                   longitude: $scope.enderecos[i].longitude
               });
           }

       }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS with angular-google-maps: Add Marker through fomr and Find me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125909/angularjs-with-angular-google-maps-add-marker-through-fomr-and-find-me)

Comment: `$scope.enderecos = listview;` - what does `listview` look like?

Comment: @duncan the listview is my array of lat and long, it is working fine, I can log them on the console, the problem is that is requiring an id foreach marker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
$scope.markers.push({
    id:[i],
    latitude: $scope.enderecos[i].latitude,
    longitude: $scope.enderecos[i].longitude
});
```

Where you're specifying the `id` attribute, you've got it wrapped in the array shorthand, `[ ]`

This only makes sense if you're actually accessing an array value, e.g. where you do `enderecos[i].latitude`.  Or if you're trying to pass an array to the `id` attribute, but I'm pretty sure it'll be expecting a simple string or integer.

Just change it to this and you should be fine:

```js
$scope.markers.push({
    id: i,
    latitude: $scope.enderecos[i].latitude,
    longitude: $scope.enderecos[i].longitude
});
```